# "postgres" role exists in \du but getting role "postgres" does not exist errors

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

As a preface to this question, I'm a frontend engineer, and I don't fully understand how postgres and Docker work, but we use both in our application.

For various reasons, I recently reinstalled Linuxbrew and postgresql@15. Both run and start, no problem.

However, when I try to start our application, which uses Node, Docker and some basic environment information for our DB:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_NAME=[xyz]
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=
DB_PORT=5432
```

I get the `role "postgres" does not exist`; however, if I `psql`, which uses my username, johnsoct in the shell, and `\du`, postgres does exist as a superuser.

I really don't understand why the role isn't found when it's listed in postgres' roles.

[image]

Comment: Best bet is you are not connecting to the Postgres cluster/instance you think you are. Use `psql` with `-U  postgres` and see what happens.

Comment: You have multiple servers running.  One has postgres user, the other doesn't.  Your interactive psql is connecting to one, docker is connecting to the other.  You haven't shown us enough info for us to know why that might be.

Comment: 1) I have not used Linuxbrew nor am I Mac user, but my experience with answering Brew questions is that Brew Postgres packages tend to use the OS user that did the install as the default superuser. In other words there is no `postgres` user(role) created. 2) Since you are on Ubuntu why not use the native packaging? My suggestion would be to use the PGDG repo here [Ubuntu](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). It allows you to run multiple instances of Postgres and also multiple versions of Postgres. Where multiple is all currently supported versions.